# Rails not honoring specified version when creating app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i create an app using rails with specified version it is not honoring that, even though the Gemfile write 5.2.1 it upgrades to 5.2.2 in the Gemfile.lock file

This is what i did

```
gem install rails -v 5.2.1

rails _5.2.1_ new backend-solidus -d postgresql
```

however during installation log this shows:

```
Fetching rails 5.2.2
Installing rails 5.2.2
```

Full logfile:
https://pastebin.com/qC6d2wws

Comment: I don't really know, but maybe it's on purpose. Why would you want to use lower patch version?

Comment: @MarekLipka Sometimes there might be breaking changes, this is the app that i was trying to deploy https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/issues/2989

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intentional; it's by design.

[Here is the relevant source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7bd7241e02e0769fcdb3d054e0bb1e0b77200aec/railties/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb#L264-L291), from the current `rails` master branch:

```
  def rails_gemfile_entry
    if options.dev?
      [
        GemfileEntry.path("rails", Rails::Generators::RAILS_DEV_PATH)
      ]
    elsif options.edge?
      [
        GemfileEntry.github("rails", "rails/rails")
      ]
    else
      [GemfileEntry.version("rails",
                        rails_version_specifier,
                        "Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'")]
    end
  end

  def rails_version_specifier(gem_version = Rails.gem_version)
    if gem_version.segments.size == 3 || gem_version.release.segments.size == 3
      # ~> 1.2.3
      # ~> 1.2.3.pre4
      "~> #{gem_version}"
    else
      # ~> 1.2.3, >= 1.2.3.4
      # ~> 1.2.3, >= 1.2.3.4.pre5
      patch = gem_version.segments[0, 3].join(".")
      ["~> #{patch}", ">= #{gem_version}"]
    end
  end
```

In particular, note the `~>` operator.

The use of this means that, even though your `Gemfile` will specify version `~> 5.2.1`, the actual version that `bundler` chooses to install is "the latest version that's `>= 5.2.1` and `< 5.3.0`".

Patch releases contain *small* changes - such as minor bug fixes and security patches. It is extremely rare that your code will *break* due to a patch version update; it's far *more* likely that you'll remain vulnerable to a security vulnerability if you fail to update.

Therefore rails, by default, installs the *latest patch* of the specified version.

---

If you really want to explicitly revert to rails `5.2.1`, you may edit the `Gemfile` to say:

```
rails '5.2.1'
```

then, re-run `bundle update`.

Comment: Well, unfortunately the rails app that i am trying to deploy is breaking in particular with v5.2.2 https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/issues/2989.